# migrate file exists but no model for rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

migrate file exists but no model for rails application.There are user and book model.I created join table between user and book model.
I write console : rails g migration CreateJoinTableBooksUsers books users
rake:db migrate

```
**schema.rb**
 create_table "books", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "author"
    t.integer "page_count"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.boolean "status"
    t.string "user_id"
    t.boolean "barter_status"
  end

  create_table "books_users", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "book_id", null: false
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "username"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
    t.index ["username"], name: "index_users_on_username", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "comments", "books"
  add_foreign_key "comments", "users"
end


**migrate**
class CreateJoinTableBooksUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_join_table :books, :users do |t|
       t.index [:book_id, :user_id]
       t.index [:user_id, :book_id]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Creating a migration doesn't create a model or a controller.

Comment: Creating a migration dosen't create a model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A migration creates the tables in the database but doesn't create anything else.

But, for a true join table, you don't need a model:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

```
# app/models/user.rb

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :books
end

# app/models/books.rb

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

**IF** you need `scope`s, `callback`s, or `methods` on `BooksUsers`, you can use the `has_many :through` option:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many

```
# app/models/user.rb

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books_users
  has_many :books, through: :books_users
end

# app/models/books.rb

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books_users
  has_many :users, through: :books_users
end
```

In this case, you'll need to generate a model:

```
rails generate model BooksUsers
```